# How do I add and remove content within a div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I already have a function that adds content to a div once an image is clicked; however, I want the content to be removed once the same image is clicked a second time. Is there a simple way to do this?

Is there also a way for the function that adds content to also appear with a number field next to it?

Here is the function that I used to add content.

```
function frenchBread(){
      var div = document.getElementById("orderBox");

      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "French Bread" + "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Toggle a boolean flag on and off to track whether you need to show or hide the content.  Or, simply see if the content is already visible or not.

Comment: Show us how you add the content.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable to determine if the image was clicked or not.

### Edit

Forgot to assign `is_clicked` :)

### Edit Again

Added the `input` field next to the "Frech Bread" text.

```js
var is_clicked = false;

function frenchBread(){
  
  var div = document.getElementById("orderBox");
  var curr = div.innerHTML, frenchy = 'French Bread <input type="number" name="amount"><br>';
  
  if ( is_clicked ) {
    var tmp = div.innerHTML;
    curr = tmp.replace(frenchy, "");
    div.innerHTML = curr;
    is_clicked = false;
  } else {
    div.innerHTML = curr + frenchy
    is_clicked = true;
  }

      
}
```

```html
<img src="" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; background: black;" onclick="frenchBread()" />
<div id="orderBox">
  An item here <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check for the content in innerHTML:

```
function frenchBread() {
  var div = document.getElementById("orderBox");

  if(var.innerHTML == "") {
    div.innerHTML += "French Bread" + "<input type='number' /><br />";
  } else {
    div.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

**Edit:** even shorter with the ternary operator, although less readable:

```
function frenchBread() {
  var div = document.getElementById("orderBox");

  div.innerHTML = if(var.innerHTML == "") ? "French Bread" + "<input type='number' /><br />" : "";
}
```

**Edit:** added the number field in both versions.

Comment: This isn't really what OP asked for.

Comment: Sry, forgot the number field, which really is not so much more. I thought the important part of the question was the functionality of adding/removing the content.

Comment: He also wanted the ability to revert back to the previous text if they click the image again.